# Specific Builder for Parameterized Type

Tags: generics, scala, types, builder, parameterized

I'm trying to write a class in scala that wraps a (parameterized) collection and overrides it's foreach method.  What it does with the foreach method is unimportant for the purpose of this question, so lets say it just prints each element out as it's visited.  So ideally, we'd be able to use the wrapper as follows:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
scala> val b = MyWrapper(a)
scala> b.foreach{ x => x }
1
2
3
4
5
```

The key is that I want this to work with any iterable; not just a list.  So my first attempt was something like what follows

```
class MyWrapper[A, S[A] <: Iterable[A]]( val s: S[A] with IterableLike[A, S[A]]) 
      extends IterableLike[A, S[A]] {

        override def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit = {
          iterator.foreach{ x => println(x); f(x) }
        }  
 }
```

However, for this class to be concrete, we need an iterator method and a newBuilder method.  The iterator method is no problem, we can just "steal" s's iterator like so:

```
override def iterator = s.iterator
```

The problem is when I try to define newBuilder.  I need the builder to return an S[A].  However, S[A] is a parameterized collection that is bounded by Iterable[A].  Thus all of my attempts using genericBuilder or getting the companion object's builder result in an Iterable[A] rather than an S[A], with the corresponding error messages

```
[error] method newBuilder in trait TraversableLike of type => scala.collection.mutable.Builder[A,S[A]] is not defined
[error] method seq in trait Parallelizable of type => scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A] is not defined
```

How can I obtain a builder that builds the *specific type*, S[A], rather than the generic bounded type Iterable[A]?  Is this even possible?  Any help in understanding the idiomatic Scala way to do this (or any way that actually works) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the answer your question, but I do wish to know if you can just pimp a method on iterable?  If so, you can get what you want by providing a 'wrappedForeach' instead with a few lines of code.

Comment: Have you considered using a `Proxy` instead?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  I wasn't aware of Proxies before your comment.  It there a resource (other than the raw API) where I can learn about them?  Thanks!

Comment: Looking further into proxies, it seems that what I actually want can't be achieved with them.  In particular, I wanted to override the foreach method because so many other methods are implemented in terms of it.  So really, my motivation was to change the behavior of foreach, and have an appropriately modified filter/map/etc.

Answer (score 2):

*IterableLike* (and the other *XxxLike* traits) abstract over the return type by delegating to a *Builder* that has to be specific for each collection type. Hence what you are trying cannot work.

You could create a generic wrapper *MyWrapperLike[A, B]* and a couple of specific wrappers *MySeqWrapper[A] extends MyWrapperLike[A, Seq[A]]* (same for *Set*, *Map*, *List*, etc.), i.e. mimic the design of the Scala collection library.

Comment: That's interesting.  So the fact that I have a specific (but parameterized) type for S[A] doesn't allow me to access S[A]'s specific builder in any way?  I guess that's just because the nominal type bound on S[A] only ensures that it's Iterable, right?  Can I get the concrete type in some way (e.g. using a Manifest)?