# Why does scalac only emit variance errors with certain access modifiers?

Tags: scala, collections, types, covariance, access-modifiers

This code does not compile:

```scala
trait Invariant[T]
trait Covariant[+T] {
  protected val example: Invariant[T]
}
```

```
error: covariant type T occurs in invariant position in type => Invariant[T] of value example
  protected val example: Invariant[T]
                ^
one error found
```

However, this code compiles just fine:

```scala
trait Invariant[T]
trait Covariant[+T] {
  protected[this] val example: Invariant[T]
}
```

After some experimentation, it appears that the variance error occurs only when the access modifier is not scoped to `this`. These both fail:

```scala
val example: Invariant[T]
private val example: Invariant[T] = ???
```

While `private[this]` also works.

I see similar behavior when the type is contravariant instead of invariant.

I feel like I'm missing something about how Scala's type system works. Why does the compiler behave this way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28947134/3625 for the origin story of this question.

Comment: If you need more information about `private` vs `private[this]`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727849/3625 *almost* answers my question, but @denisphillips mentions mutable vars as the important factor, while my example doesn't have any mutability.